# PHP display individual pdf pages

Tags: php, pdf

Is it possible, using PHP, to display an individual pages from a pdf file. For example if I have a 5 page pdf file and I wish to display only the n-th page?

I did some google searching on this but nothing useful came up really, so I wonder if it's possible at all.

Thank,

Comment: You need to show that you made some effort in implementing this. For example you can try running a 3rd party program that splits PDFs and then return just one of the spit pages (there's probably other ways to do this too). However this question is too broad to allow anyone to provide a full answer.

Comment: Google search - that was my effort :) I do not want to mess about with the file (ex, splitting as you suggested), just simply display page X from the document. Maybe somewhere out there is a solution that I am not aware of, but if it cannot be done I will go down the hard route of messing with the file

Comment: You know you can split the file into pages without deleting the original file? The pages can be seen as a temporarily stored thing (which you need anyway be that as a file on disk or somewhere in memory). Again. Just one idea out of (possibly) many out there.